# HTML block caching regularly is invalidated

Tags: cache, block-cache, loadbalancing

I got a problem on a running magento site (CE 1.8.1.0), which got the BLOCK_HTML cache regulary invalidated (even without product/categories edit). The website was tested on 2 different environment without constating this caching issue, the main difference is that the final server is, in fact, two servers managed with load-balancing. They're plugged on the same database and got the /var folder and /media folder shared

My question is : is there any file generation outside /var and /var/cache that should be shared between the two servers ? After thinking of the issue, and if it's a consequence of the loadbalancing it should be something about files present on one server, but not the other. If it's not a consequence of the load-balancing i'm lost though.

Comment: Same issue on my CE 1.8.1 install as well. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: I know this is an old closed thread but it was likely a cron job causing the problem and you had Magento cron set up in one environment but not in the other.